# Slim: Multiple GET names for 1 url

Tags: php, eloquent, twig, slim

I am trying to add a video section in my website using twig, slim, and eloquent. Now here is what I have for my route for my 'watch' pages

```
<?php

$app->get('/watch/:series/:episode', function($series, $episode) use($app){
    $video = $app->video->where('series', $series)->where('episode', $episode)->first();
    $app->render('videos/watch.php', [
        'video' => $video
    ]);
})->name('videos.watch');
```

now what I want to do is also have it to where when if they do not specifiy an episode number (i.e. type in 'watch/seriesName/') it defaults to the lowest episode number. My database structure is 'id', 'title', 'series', 'episode' (all that really matter to this issue).

In the midst of asking this question I actually figured it out. I will answer my own question so that others who may have the same problem may know what I did.

Here is my video class just in case anyone is interested in how to utilize my video class (not sure if it was the best way of going about handling videos but it works)

```
<?php

namespace BiosystemStudios\Video;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
use JBBCode\Parser;
use JBBCode\DefaultCodeDefinitionSet;

class Video extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'content_video';

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'series',
        'episode',
        'location',
        'description',
        'category',
        'is_youtube',
        'youtube_link',
        'views'
    ];

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        $parser = new Parser();
        $parser->addCodeDefinitionSet(new DefaultCodeDefinitionSet());
        $text = $this->description;
        $parser->parse($text);
        return $parser->getAsHtml();
    }

    public function getLocation()
    {
        return $this->location;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename the first get request to "videos.watch.episode" then create this get request:

```
$app->get('/watch/:series/', function($series) use($app){
    $video = $app->video->where('series', $series)->first();
    $app->render('videos/watch.php', [
        'video' => $video
    ]);
})->name('videos.watch');
```